# How to make database connectivity in ASP.NET core with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, asp.net-core, database-connection

How to make database connection in ASP.NET core with postgres SQL ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to make database connection in ASP.NET core with postgres SQL?

There are two ways you add your `postgresql` database along with the `asp.net core` project.

Using follwing way:

- `ADO.net connection provider`
- `Nuget extension: Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL`

**`ADO.net connection provider`**

Here would just need the `NpgsqlConnection` connection builder class which will execute your `sql` on `Postgre sql` database server. See the example below:

**`C# ASP.NET Core & Postgre SQL Ado.net example:`**

```
  NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=postgres;Password=pwd;Database=postgres;");
    
    conn.Open();
    
    // Passing PostGre SQL Function Name
    NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("EXE GetEmployeePrintInfo", conn);
    
    // Execute the query and obtain a result set
    NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    
    // Reading from the database rows
    List<string> listOfManager = new List<string>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string WSManager = reader["WSManager"].ToString(); // Remember Type Casting is required here it has to be according to database column data type
        listOfManager.Add(WSManager);
    }
    reader.Close();

    command.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
```

**`Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL:`**

You have to add `Nuget extension` into the project reference from [`manage Nuget Packages`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/) using `Visual studio`. `Entity framework core` has this functionality for many database providers. Just follow below steps on `visual studio`

[image]

**`ConfigureServices in startup.cs:`**
Once you successfully added the `Nuget package` then you have to update following code on your project `ConfigureServices` under `startup.cs`

```cs
        services.AddDbContext<YourDatabaseContextClassName>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourDatabaseContextStringNameFromAppsettings")));
```

> **`Note:`** If you need any example for `entityframework` and `Postgre SQL` [implementation you can have look here](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/)

For further assistance you can have look on [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#current-providers). Hope it would guide you accordingly.

Comment: Is using dapper a recommended way? Because I faced weird issues when connected with certain asp.net versions. For example I can't invoke functions of PostgreSQL through dapper, seems like it conflicts with PostgreSQL SPs.

Comment: It both has pros and corn depending on the scenario actually. However, you could post new question pointing your issue and concern that would be great to check.

Comment: It seems like it was not an issue with dapper itself but a change in NpgSQL. I posted a question regarding it if you are interested in helping https://stackoverflow.com/q/75714210/5765939