# How to execute Postgresql functions from .NET 7 using Dapper without listing the data types of all parameters

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I'm trying to transfer my .NET 5 web API code to a .NET 7. I have a singleton service called `DataManager` which implements the inferface `IDataManager`. One of the functions is `Execute`
and there are other C# functions called Get, GetMany and Insert, Update and BulkInsert.

I added `CommandType.Text` by default to execute queries rather than just functions. When calling functions I call with `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

After the new NpgSQL change, functions don't work like below.

### **Here's how I used to call in .NET 5 app:**

### The `Execute` C# function in `DataManager`:

```
public virtual async Task<int> Execute(string command, object? parms = null, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text)
        {
            int result = 0;
            using var dbConnection = await GetConnection();
            using (var transaction = await dbConnection.BeginTransactionAsync())
            {
                try
                {
                    result = (await dbConnection.QueryAsync<int>(command, parms, transaction: transaction, 60, commandType)).FirstOrDefault();
                    transaction.Commit();

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

### Here's how I'm calling the `Execute` function to run a PostgreSQL function;

```
 public async Task<int> DeleteIdea(long id)
 {
    return await _dataManager.Execute("delete_idea", new { _id = id }, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
 }
```

---

### Now here's the changed code for `.NET 7` app.

### The `Execute` C# function in DataManager:

*Made some changes to be more generic.*

```
public virtual async Task<T> Execute<T>(string functionName, object? parameters = null)
{
    using var dbConnection = await GetConnection();
    using var transaction = await dbConnection.BeginTransactionAsync();

    var command = new StringBuilder($"SELECT * FROM {functionName}(");
    if (parameters != null)
    {
        var paramNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (var property in parameters.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            paramNames.Add($"@{property.Name}");
        }
        command.Append(string.Join(",", paramNames));
    }
    command.Append(");");

    try
    {
        var result = await dbConnection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(command.ToString(), parameters, transaction);
        transaction.Commit();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackAsync();
        throw;
    }
}
```

*The `Execute` function is called in a similar way to the .NET 5 app.*

```
  public async Task<int> DeleteIdea(long id)
  {
      return await _dataManager.Execute<int>("delete_idea", new { _id = id });
  }
```

Above code will work for `string` or for `text` datatype in PostgreSQL but it will fail for types like `Int64`, `bool` and JSON types ..etc. Only solution I can think of is to individually cast each type inside the `Execute` function's `foreach` but I feel like there must be a better way.

*If there are better ways to do the same in .NET 7 or any other improvements to my code it is greatly appreciated!*

Comment: I appears you are switch from SQL Command to a Stored Procedure.  You database do not have to change.  You are using Entity and using Raw SQL to access a stored procedure is what you want to use.  With Entity a mapping is created between the c# classes and database tables/fields.  You use migrations to update database from c# classes.  Data Type do not have to change.

Comment: Can you explain bit further? I don't get what you meant. Can you give me an example

Comment: See following : https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I'm looking for a dapper solution

Comment: None of the code you posted above contains dapper methods.  There are different layers of you application and the database layer is the code posted.  You want to call a stored procedure [return await _dataManager.Execute("delete_idea", new { _id = id }, CommandType.StoredProcedure);] and you are usijng Entity [dbConnection].  the right way of calling a stored procedure with Entity is a Raw SQL.  You code changed to use a stored procedure.  Previously you were not using a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Isn't `QueryAsync` and `QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync` methods from dapper?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252483/discussion-between-lorddraagon-and-jdweng).

Comment: The Net Library has base classes for connecting to databases.  Dapper is inheriting the base classes.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do what Dapper already does. Dapper already infers the parameter types and names from the input object, so what's the point of your `Execute` method? Never mind that wrapping a SELECT in an explicit transaction is a *really* bad idea because it keeps locks for longer.

Comment: With Dapper you can eliminate *all* this code and replace it with 1-2 lines only. That's the whole point of the library. If you end up writing as much code as you would with raw ADO.NET, what's the point?

Comment: It seems the only thing that's really needed is to generate the SQL query *string* dynamically. There are many SQL builder libraries and Dapper itself has one, [Dapper.SqlBuilder](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/tree/main/Dapper.SqlBuilder). It's not a core part of the project though and not actively maintained. That's not what Dapper is about

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your input. You can leave an answer with the proper use of dapper to handle this. I think you can include a SQL builder library as well if it helps the answer. As  `Dapper.SqlBuilder` is not actively maintained I'm reluctant to use it as I will be making these changes to an enterprise application. Thanks for the help mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dynamic` for your calling code:

```
return await _dataManager.Execute<int, dynamic>("delete_idea", new { _id = id });
```

For your DataManger function, use a second generic parameter.

```
public virtual async Task<T> Execute<T, U>(string functionName, U parameters)
{
    using var dbConnection = await GetConnection();
    using var transaction = await dbConnection.BeginTransactionAsync();

    var command = new StringBuilder($"SELECT * FROM {functionName}(");
    if (parameters != null)
    {
        var paramNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (var property in parameters.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            paramNames.Add($"@{property.Name}");
        }
        command.Append(string.Join(",", paramNames));
    }
    command.Append(");");

    try
    {
        var result = await dbConnection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(command.ToString(), parameters, transaction);
        transaction.Commit();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackAsync();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution mate! This code will perfectly works if I want to query a single row. I created 2 more methods called `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteQueryMany` to handle returning row count with `ExecuteAsync` dapper method and other to return `IEnumerable` of rows with `QueryAsync<T>` dapper method. I will mark this as an answer if there are no better answers before the bounty ends.